# value coming as empty in live sum of values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select box that show a list of products. That list comes from a database, all works. Then, I have an onchange function to give me the price of that product when an item is selected and I assign it to an input - worked with a paragraph too(I need it that way so the jquery function of the sum works) - all works too. Then, I have an input that is supposed to give me the price * the quantity, and the quantity and the code works fine, except the product value. It keeps coming as 0, meaning the value comes empty. I assume it's because the Jquery function starts working when the page loads and the Javascript doesnt. How can I change it, so everytime I change the 'quantidade' value, the total gets updated?
Here's my code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="nome">Produto</label>
 <select id="produtos" onchange="getPreco()" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="morada">Quantidade</label>
 <input id="quantidade" class="form-control">
</div>
<input id="valorpreco" type="hidden">
```

```
function getPreco(){
    var idproduto = document.getElementById('produtos').value;
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:{func:4, idproduto: idproduto},
      url: "model/modelRegistarReserva.php",
      success: function(resposta){
        document.getElementById('valorpreco').value = resposta;
      }
    });
  }


  $(function(){
    $('#quantidade').keyup(function(){
      var value1 = parseFloat($('#valorpreco').val()) || 0;
      var value2 = parseFloat($('#quantidade').val()) || 0;
      $('#total').val(value1);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Why don't you temporarily change "valorpreco" to `type=text`, so you can see when the value changes?

Comment: *laughs* how awkward.... that totally helped. I was console.loging the value when I got it from the database, and it was coming with the name of the database field as well, I had just thought the code in question did that by itself and not that I was literally getting the name of the field as well. All works now, thanks!